# How to fit largest circle within Voronoi cells?

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a list of Voronoi cells and would like to place the largest circle possible within each cell. What is the best way to do that?

Many thanks,

Arthur

Comment: You mean only the bounded cells, right? Otherwise, there is no largest circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are algorithms for finding the largest circle inside a convex polygon but they're not very fast. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953623/is-there-an-simple-algorithm-for-calculating-maximum-inscribed-circle-into-a-conv